# How to download the return of a VoiceRSS API Request?

Tags: javascript, php, api, text-to-speech

I'm developing two web pages that will use the VoiceRSS Text-To-Speech feature:

1. The admin dashboard will send a request, play the audio and record the spoken string in a local database.;
2. The view page, will check the local database for any new requests recorded and play the same audio as the admin dashboard if detects a new record.

My issue is that the view page has now external internet access, meaning that in the admin dashboard request I need to download the vocalized string to an MP3 file in my server. I've already tried many things, such as different output requests, using the base64 (I get a bad request) or forcing download with javascript (doesn't work because of cross site scripting)

Knowing this, is there any away to get the return of the request and download it to a file?

This is the base code I'm using:

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.voicerss.org/?key=API_KEY&hl=en-us&v=Amy&src=Hello, world!Teste!Teste";

  
?> 

<html>

</script>

<script src="voicerss-tts.min.js"></script>
<script>
        VoiceRSS.speech({
            key: 'API_KEY',
            src: 'Hello, world!',
            hl: 'en-us',
            v: 'Linda',
            r: 0, 
            c: 'mp3',
            f: '44khz_16bit_stereo',
            ssml: false
        });
</script>

</html>
```

Feel free to ask any questions.

Any ideas in PHP or Javascript are welcomed.

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0):

If You can not download using JavaScript use php sdk api. You can play and download easy. Here is the code how

```
$audio_player="<audio controls='controls'><source src='data:audio/mpeg;base64,".base64_encode($audioStream)."'></audio>";
echo $audio_player;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).